# Installation of apache on aws throwing an error

Tags: amazon-web-services

When i try and run the command

```
yum install -y httpd.x86_64
```

it throws the following error

```
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
No package httpd.86_64 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

What should i do to troubleshoot?

Comment: Looks like a typo to me. Try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the standard httpd package

```
sudo yum update
sudo yum install httpd
```